# Trying to read a text file in java - Error: File of directory does not exist - LINUX

Tags: java, file

Im just learning java and in my current class im learning how to read a text file. I made everything the teacher did, but when i try running it i get an error:  File of directory does not exist.  (ERROR: /home/jean/Documentos/Livros.txt (Arquivo ou diretório inexistente))

Im using linux, what did i make wrong?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeArquivos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("/home/jean/Documentos/Livros.txt");
        Scanner scan = null;

        try {
            scan = new Scanner(file);
            while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(scan.hasNextLine());
            }`enter code here`
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            if(scan != null) {
            scan.close();
            }   
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the result of "ls -a /home/jean/Documentos" ?

Comment: Part file does not exist or part file is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How to check part of directory.

```
Step 1 Open command line (windows + R type CMD) enter.
Step 2 Type cd /
Step 3 Type cd /home/jean/Documentos --> enter --> If command error part is incorrect.
Step 4 Type ls --> Fine file Livros.txt
```

If file found part is correct.

If file not found part is incorrect.

:::::::::Update::::::::

Try is code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("/home/jean/Documentos/Livros.txt");
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String st;
        while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(st);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Hop is help.

Comment: Hey dude, i could found the problem. I was not saving the file with the extension included. After i save like Livros.txt it worked.
But, now i got another problem. My program just ran, but its in a infinite looping of TRUE in it output. It should list the Livros.txt content. Whats wrong with that?

Comment: What is result you expect.

Comment: just changed scan.hasNextLine() to scan.NextLine(), in the output line and it worked. Tks a lot.